# Get the date between 2 dates using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

In `node.js` I need to get the date within the date range of particular gap.

Consider two dates:

```
startDate:2016-07-10T00:00:00.000Z,
payByDate:"13"(13th of every month);
endDate:2016-10-08T00:00:00.000Z
```

I need an array of dates of monthly or weekly gap between these 2 dates.

My result Should be:(Monthly gap)

```
[2016-07-13T00:00:00.000Z,
 2016-08-13T00:00:00.000Z,
 2016-09-13T00:00:00.000Z]
```

**EDIT:**
 My startdate is `2016-07-10T00:00:00.000Z` , so i can calculate the noOfmonths using endDate-startdate, but the array entry should be by `payByDate`.

I am using `MOMENT.JS`, but its returning only `noOfMonths` not the dates. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Now is it possible to calculate the calculate the Above array.Please note that "payByDate" is string.

Comment: What is the monthly gap between 2016-01-31 and 2016-03-31? And  between 2015-01-31 and 2015-03-31?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [manipulate method in moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) to add a month to the starting date until you reach the second date.

Consider this code. Assuming that the first date and the last date are already moments when they are passed into this function, you can use the diff and manipulate methods to create an array of dates by month in between the two different dates:

**EDIT:**

```
function monthsBetween(payByDate, startDate, lastDate) {
  var months = [];

  //finds nearest date to the start date that is on the payByDate
  var currentDate = startDate.date(parseInt(payByDate));

  //checks if the date is after the startDate and adds a month if it is
  if(!currentDate.isSameOrAfter(startDate)){
    currentDate = currentDate.add(1, 'months');
  }

  while (currentDate.isSameOrBefore(lastDate)) {
    months.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = currentDate.add(1, 'months');
  }

  return months;
}
```

Comment: That should be a comment, it's not an answer.

Comment: @RobG Cannot commet yet because of rep :( I agree, it should be a comment though.

Comment: @Subburaj Do you want it on every 10th from the current date to the end date?

Comment: @Subburaj See the edit to my code. It should now return a list of all dates that are in between the start and end date that fall on a given payByDate.

Comment: @Subburaj Does this code work for you, or did I misunderstand the edit?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getMonth()` function to get the month of your date. then keep adding one to it till you reach the end date.

```
var arrayDates = [];
arrayDates.push(startDate);
var tempDate = new Date(new Date(startDate).setMonth(startDate.getMonth()+1));
while(tempDate < endDate)
{
   arrayDates.push(tempDate);
   var tempDate = new Date(new Date(tempDate).setMonth(tempDate.getMonth()+1));
}
```

Abouve logic will work for monthly gap. to get array of weekly gap, use `getDate()` function and keep adding 7 to it till you reach the end Date

Comment: Note that 2016-01-31 plus one month gives 2016-03-02, which might be unexpected.

Comment: @RobG Yes you are right. I just tested the code and found out that it will not work correctly for the month of February